# Angular2: How to use css calc() with some component value?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I want to calculate  `div` height based on the component value by using `calc` CSS function. The error it gave me:

> TypeError: co.calc is not a function

My code:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'height': calc(100% - + assetScreenSize + px)}">
</div>
```

Comment: `[ngStyle]="{'height': 'calc(100% -' + assetScreenSize + 'px)'}"`

Comment: Thanks,  Need to add space after minus sign ` - ` .   correct: `[ngStyle]="{'height':'calc(100% - ' + assetScreenSize + 'px)'}"`

Answer (score 10):

Your syntax is incorrect. The correct way would be:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'height': 'calc(100% -' + assetScreenSize + 'px)'}">
</div>
```

Comment: You have an extra quote. It should be 
{'height': 'calc(100% -' + assetScreenSize + 'px)'}